# Empty header cart in opencart 2.2.0

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to implement an  empty mini cart in header of my OC web site. I have made a link button and tried to incorporate some code to make it clear my mini cart, but it is not working. The code is like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="<? php header('Location: http://mysitelocation/cart') $this->cart->clear(); ?>">Clear the mini cart</a>
```

Any suggestions as to how to do this differently because this is not clearing my cart. Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I managed to solve this.

The button should be like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="clearCart(); window.location.reload();" ><?php echo "Empty mini cart" ?></a></p>
```

It is calling clearCart() function and this function should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function clearCart() {
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/clearcart',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function(json) {
                      $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
                      if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
                          location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
                      } else {
                          $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
                      }
                  }
              });
            }
            </script>
```

Also, it is reloading the page after clearing the cart (this is also called within my link button above.) I hope this helps someone. Cheers!